# How to result from head command to sed to add to the first line of the file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I would like to add the text which is the result from `head` command to `sed`. Can I achieve this in a one liner?

This is what I have come up so far.

```
header=`head -n 1 csv1.csv`
sed -e '1 i\'$'\n''$header' another_csv.csv
```

What I don't know is how do I pass the result from one command to another command. I tried usnig `xargs` but no luck. I don't know how to pass that as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '1r file2' -e 'q' file1
```

or perhaps use:

```
head -1 file1 | cat - file2
```

Comment: For the benefit of others who are (like me) at first puzzled by the `sed` trickery: `1r file2` simply prints file2 (corresponding to `another_csv.csv` in the OP's approach) to stdout; `'q' file1` reads and prints the first line from file1 (corresponding to `csv1.csv`, from which to get the header) then quits, effectively printing the 1st line (the header) only; since `sed` *appends* file content read via `r` to the overall output, the header line is printed first.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something it can be:

```
head -1 csv1.csv && cat another.csv
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't save to the file do I have to pipe again?

Comment: @toy: You have 2 options if you wanted to redirect the output from *both* commands to a file: (a) use a subshell: `(head -1 csv1.csv && cat another.csv) > outFile` or (b) use grouping (technically better, but trickier syntax-wise): `{ head -1 csv1.csv && cat another.csv; } > outFile`

Answer (score 2):

**awk**:

```
awk 'NR==1{getline h<"csv1.csv";print h}7 ' another.csv
```

test:

```
kent$  head f c
==> f <==
1
2
3
4
5

==> c <==
10
9
8

kent$  awk 'NR==1{getline h<"c";print h}7 ' f
10
1
2
3
4
5
```

**gnu sed**

```
kent$  sed '1s/.*/head -n 1 c;echo &/ge' f 
10
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava's solution is simpler, but just to show the corrected version of the OP's approach:

### Linux

```
sed -e "1 i $(head -n 1 csv1.csv)" another_csv.csv
```

- On Linux you need not place the text passed to `i` on a separate line (thus no need for `\` and the literal newline (`$'\n'`).
- In the original approach, `'$header'` was placed in *single* quotes, preventing string interpolation - double quotes are needed: `"$header"` (in my reformulation I used double quotes for the entire sed command (not recommended in general) and directly placed the command inside, using command substitution (`$(...)`).

### OSX

Same as above, except `\` and a newline (`$'\n'`) must be inserted right after the `i`:

```
sed -e '1 i\'$'\n'"$(head -n 1 csv1.csv)" another_csv.csv
```

(The equivalent of:

`sed -e "1 i\

$(head -n 1 csv1.csv)

" another_csv.csv`

)